# Java Converting do-while loop with while loop

Tags: java

I am implementing a simple sorting class, and was wondering how I would implement this using a while loop rather than a do-while loop.

The **outer loop is executed once for each item in the ‘names’ list.** However, it’s a do-while loop, which is always executed at least once. This will lead to an incorrect result if ‘names’ is the empty list. It should be replaced with a while loop.

**SORT CLASS**

```
public class Sort {

public static ArrayList<Name> sort1(ArrayList<Name> names) {

    ArrayList<Name> results;

    results = new ArrayList<Name>();

    int count = names.size();
    do {

        Name firstName = new Name("zzz", "zzz");
        for (Name name : names) {
            if (name.getFirstName().compareTo(firstName.getFirstName()) < 0
                    || name.getFirstName().equals(firstName.getFirstName())
                            && name.getSurName().compareTo(firstName.getSurName()) < 0) {
                firstName = new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getSurName());
            }
        }

        results.add(firstName);

        names.remove(firstName);

        count--;

    } while (count > 0);

    return results;
}}}
```

**NAME CLASS**

```
class Name {

String firstName;
String surName;

public Name() {
}

public Name(String firstName, String surName) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surName = surName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
}

public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
}

public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + surName;
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
    String fname = ((Name) other).firstName;
    String sname = ((Name) other).surName;
    if (firstName.equals(fname) && surName.equals(sname)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm? Just use `while (count > 0) { <while-body> }`? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: How about a for-loop? `for (int count = names.size(); count > 0; count--) { ... }`

Comment: As others said, just replace the do-while loop with a while loop (or a for loop). Also, you should read up about [how to write a correct equals method](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html) for your Name class. And lastly, it would make sense to write a `compareTo` method for your Name class, which would make your for-loop in your sort method much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Sort {

private static void doIterate(List<Name> names, List<Name> results) {
        Name firstName = new Name("zzz", "zzz");
        for (Name name : names) {
            if (name.getFirstName().compareTo(firstName.getFirstName()) < 0
                    || name.getFirstName().equals(firstName.getFirstName())
                            && name.getSurName().compareTo(firstName.getSurName()) < 0) {
                firstName = new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getSurName());
            }
        }

        results.add(firstName);

        names.remove(firstName);
}

public static ArrayList<Name> sort1(ArrayList<Name> names) {

    ArrayList<Name> results;

    results = new ArrayList<Name>();

    int count = names.size();
    doIterate(names, results);
    count--;
    while (count > 0) {
      doIterate(names, results);
      count--;
    }

    return results;
}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. great idea.

Comment: This one still does at least one iteration (it calls iterate outside of the while loop) so it still doesn't work for an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `do` with your `while (count > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the while loop is always executed once, I would do a check prior to the loop to see if names has values in it.  If yes, then do the do/while loop.  Otherwise, skip it.